# When to use did in question?

Tags: questions

I have confusion about using did in questions ?

a ) Let me know when did we change this ?

b ) Let me know when we changed this?

Both sound correct to me .

Is there any rule about useing did in english questions?

Comment: You confuse the issue by including the words *Let me know* before the "question". We often follow those words with a syntactically valid question such as ***When did we change this**?* (with "do-support" and subject+verb inversion, as is the standard for questions in English), but idiomatically we also often just retain the normal word order appropriate for a *noun phrase* (as typically used within a statement). Note that the second version *doesn't* work unless preceded by something like *I want to know...* (so *When we changed this?* is ***invalid,*** although it's common coming from nns).

Comment: "Let me know..." is grammatically an imperative, not a question.

Answer (score 3):

A question:

> When did we change this?

A request:

> (Please,) Let me know when we changed this.

A request, combined with a question:

> Please, let me know the following: when did we change this?

So, for correct *word order* it is important to choose a form (a question, a usual sentence or something more complicated).

Answer (score 0):

To my BrE ears the first two sentences have slightly different meanings. The first question:"When did we change this?" conveys an aggressive tone, as if the boss is asking his subordinates why something he always thought was X is now not-X. It is obviously less aggressive than "when did **you** change this?" but it is aggressive, nonetheless.

The second question is more nearly neutral, but if I were a subordinate and the question was asked by my boss, I should be a little nervous.

The third is just a longer way of asking the second question.